# yum repo sync "Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'rhui-client-config-server-8'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, yum, rhel8

While doing yum provides or yum update on AWS Instance of RHEL 8.0 (Ootpa) a "rhui-client-config-server-8" repository giving Failed to Synchronize error.

Steps followed

- yum clean cache (no success)
- yum clean all (no success)

Comment: did you remove the cache directory? `rm -rf /var/cache/yum`

Comment: Yes.. but it did not have cached anything under /var/cache/yum folder instead it was in /var/cache/dnf , by doing sudo rm -rf /var/cache/dnf/* and then yum update resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 8 is based on dnf (dandified YUM), so you would want to use "dnf clean cache" or "dnf clean all" instead of yum.  Additionally, if that didn't work, you would want to look in /var/cache/dnf rather than /var/cache/yum.

Comment: Using `yum` doesn't make a difference. It will redirect to `dnf` and do the same. One can even install `yum` or create an alias for it that points at `dnf` but even that isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo yum or elevate to root for aws rhel 8; no need to use dnf (although trying to download a package using dnf did make me realize I didn't have enough permissions).

Answer (score 0):

With RedHat 7 or 8, one way to clean all those caches is to run this command as Sudo

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
```

For those wondering why “yum clean” or “yum clean all” does not clean/remove all caches. It is because “yum clean” or “yum clean all” only removes the cache of repositories which are **enabled** in /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo. In other words, cache that are either presently **deactivated** or from **previous RedHat version** will not be clear. This is per Yum manual. Which reads: « Note that "all files" in the commands below means "all files in currently enabled repositories". » Source at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html#CLEAN_OPTIONS

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS 8 run

```
dnf update -y --releasever=8
```

Then you can install everything else.